# Bootstrap styles not applying within a Shadow DOM on Chrome 35

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, polymer, shadow-dom

I've working with Bootstrap 3.1.1 and Polymer 0.2.4 for a long time and, suddenly -it may have been since the last Chrome auto-update (Version 35.0.1916.114)- Bootstrap stopped styling Shadow DOM elements. I've been able to check that the CSS classes within those nodes do not appear when inspecting the (Shadow) DOM with Chrome DevTools. In other browsers, such as Firefox, it is still working.

I don't know whether this is something I'm missing or some kind of bug, but this odd styling behaviour can be seen too directly on jsbin. I'm including two adapted chunks of code extracted from an actual component to illustrate my problem:

- http://jsbin.com/yugih/1/ (working example)
- http://jsbin.com/maleg/1/ (non-working example)

Please, notice that what I wanted to stress in the previous examples were just the differences between how CSS styling is being applied (or not).

Thanks in advance,

Nacho

P.S. I've also checked it with Polymer 0.3.1 with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between native Shadow DOM and the polyfill. The first example works because the styles are not crossing a shadow dom boundary. They're just applied to the light dom.

The solution is to include the stylesheets in your element. More info:

- https://twitter.com/polymer/status/468803383982190592
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/polymer-dev/bootsrap$20style/polymer-dev/lv8JznvOH4s/1mzv5oadRbgJ

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric. I realised my error! What really puzzles me is that, just a few days ago, my code actually worked! For the sake of re-usability, I coded a `wc-loader` tag responsible for including globally-scoped libraries (BS, jQuery, ...). Up to some days ago, this solution worked because these global libraries permeated the shadow DOM. I now realise that this goes against `shadow dom` encapsulation. What would be your opinion about using this kind of `wc-loader`s? Is there any way of implementing them (to avoid repeating `link` tags in each template)?

Comment: We're told by the Blink engineers that including duplicate stylesheets in an element is low cost. From Elliot: "In Chrome 35 `@import` or `@media` will disable the stylesheet sharing. In Chrome 36 only `@import` will disable the sharing. Bootstrap should be fine in 36. I think it has `@media` rules which caused issues in Chrome 35. I know the `@import` thing is a footgun. We hope to fix it eventually. :)"

Comment: Fore 3rd party libs, you can use an HTML import to include the dependency in your app: https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/blob/master/firebase-element.html#L1...which just wraps the lib: https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/blob/master/firebase-import.html

Comment: Hi Eric. We tried the solution that you proposed (turning wc-loader into a simple page, which was included with an import). The result is that it seems to work when the host page is an HTML one but it fails when it is a template.